# parseInt some value in object array using lodash or pure javaScript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have some object array likes this

```
{ 
    date: '1490547600000',
    details: [ 
            { 
                time: '01.00 - 02.00',
                title: 'go sleep',
                location: 'bedroom' 
            },
                { 
                time: '08.30 - 09.30',
                title: 'go to school',
                location: 'my school' 
            } 
    ] 
}
```

I want to change date '1490547600000' to int

```
{ 
    date: 1490547600000,
    details: [ 
            { 
                time: '01.00 - 02.00',
                title: 'go sleep',
                location: 'bedroom' 
            },
                { 
                time: '08.30 - 09.30',
                title: 'go to school',
                location: 'my school' 
            } 
    ] 
}
```

I'm studying lodash and I try to find some solution to solve it likes using _.map

but I still don't understand its concept.

I used lodash because I wanna solve it minimal coding
but if you have another javascript solution, please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: assign object to some var(eg: objVar) now set objVar.data = parseInt(objVar.data)

Comment: Please share you code as well

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hcwrLdvp/)

Comment: oh i see, I can use simple code to solve this, obj.date = parseInt(obj.date);

Answer (score 0):

You dont need loadash to convert it to a number. You can use 
    *date : Number('1490547600000');*

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: They're not on about using loadash to convert a string to a number, they're on about using loadash to iterate their array.

Comment: He clearly said that he only wants to convert the '1490547600000' value into 1490547600000 and added at the end that if we have another javascript solution (without using loadash) we should let him know.

Answer (score 0):

based on the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Using_map_to_reformat_objects_in_an_array

you could try something like

```
//your array of objects
var kvArray = [
{ 
    date: '1490547600000',
    details: [ 
            { 
                time: '01.00 - 02.00',
                title: 'go sleep',
                location: 'bedroom' 
            },
            { 
                time: '08.30 - 09.30',
                title: 'go to school',
                location: 'my school' 
           }
          ] 
}, {...\\other objects formatted same way}]


var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(function(obj) { 
   var rObj = {};
   rObj[obj.date] = parseInt(obj.date);
   return rObj;
});
// rObj should return the contents of kvArray but with date being an int for all the objects
// heres a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xkdbkgj9
```